# Disable\Remove Custom Product Attribute

Tags: custom-attributes, http-request

When I do a GET request on a product, M2 returns some custom attributes that I have no interest in, such as 'is_recurring'. Is it possible to 'disable' a custom attribute so it does not appear in product GET requests?

Thanks!

Comment: You can remove it from directly database.

Comment: @SureshChikani Thanks for the reply. I realize that I could just remove it from the database, but is there a cleaner or less permanent way of doing it?

Comment: if you will remove it from database, attribute will permanent remove.

Comment: @SureshChikani, I understand it would be permanent. What I'm looking for is something 'less' permanent.

Comment: How do you check GET request?

Comment: You can disabled from attribute.

Comment: @SureshChikani can you elaborate on how you would "disable from attribute"?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable attributes from

> Store >> Attributes >> Product >> open is_recurring >> Storefront
>   Properties >> Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront && Used in
>   Product Listing >> No

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the Storefront Properties and they all seem to be already set to 'No' for 'is_recurring'. However, 'is_recurring' still shows up in the body of GET responses under 'custom_attributes'.